# jQuery alternative to nth-child selector that supports classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I have a structure like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="randomclass">...</div>
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="randomclassdifferentname">...</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="item">Item 6</div>
    <div class="item">Item 7</div>
    ...
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="anotherclass">...</div>
    <div class="item">Another item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Another item 2</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div class="item">Another item 3</div>
    ...
</div>
```

I need to select only nth **.item div** class child of a **.parent div** (counter resets for every parent node).

For example I want to select every **third "div.item"** element so I'm expecting to affect elements with content "**Item 3**", "**Item 6**", "**Another item 3**".

Rules:

- Desired classes are always applied to a "div" element (maybe not important).
- Parents have always "parent" class and are also always "div" elements.
- Amongst divs there can be other divs (or any other type of element) with random class name (or without) and these must not interfere with the nth counter.
- Elements also can be nested so every item class element can in addition contain another parent class element and that again another item class elements.

Unfortunatelly **CSS selector**:

```
div.parent div.item:nth-child(3n)
```

with **nth-child()** is not working properly. Although the effects are applied only to elements with given class, the counting itself is not correct because it counts also elements without given class.

As I doubt that there will be pure CSS solution and also because I'm in fact using this as a jQuery selector, I would like some simple jQuery alternative. Thank you guys for any help you can give me.

Comment: I think you'll need to use `$("div.parent").each()` to process each parent separately, then use `$(this).children(".item")` to get all the items, and then loop over them by 3.

Comment: I think you cannot do this in css alone need some javscript support

Comment: @PHPglue: As you can see in this fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/m7rLedsu/) it's not working unfortunately. Or am I missing something?

Comment: `nth-child()` is nth child of parentNode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter the items based on the index they have in the parent, in relation to other items with the same class

```js
$('.item').filter(function(_,item) {
    return ($(item).siblings('.item').addBack().index(item)+1) % 3 === 0;
}).css('color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="randomclass">...</div>
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="randomclassdifferentname">...</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="item">Item 6</div>
    <div class="item">Item 7</div>
    ...
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="anotherclass">...</div>
    <div class="item">Another item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Another item 2</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div class="item">Another item 3</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Short and effective. It just will take a moment for me to fully understand the notation. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want `nth` element of some jQuery collection you need to use the [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) selector on that collection. As in...

```js
var allItems = $('.parent').find('.item');
for (i = 1; i <= allItems.length/3; i++) {
  allItems.eq((i*3)-1).css({'border':'1px solid red'})
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="randomclass">...</div>
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="randomclassdifferentname">...</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="item">Item 6</div>
    <div class="item">Item 7</div>
    ...
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="anotherclass">...</div>
    <div class="item">Another item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Another item 2</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div class="item">Another item 3</div>
    ...
</div>
```

The above will keep your count throughout the collection (irrespective of parents). If you want each parent dealt with separately, use an `.each()` on `$('.parent')`s. As in...

```js
$('.parent').each( function(){
    var theseItems = $(this).find('.item');
    for (i = 1; i <= theseItems.length/3; i++) {
        theseItems.eq((i*3)-1).css({border:'1px solid red'})
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="randomclass">...</div>
        <div class="item">Item 1</div>
        <div class="item">Item 2</div>
        <div class="item">Item 3</div>
        <div class="randomclassdifferentname">...</div>
        <div class="item">Item 4</div>
        <div class="item">Item 5</div>
        <div class="item">Item 6</div>
        <div class="item">Item 7</div>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="anotherclass">...</div>
        <div class="item">Another item 1</div>
        <div class="item">Another item 2</div>
        <div>...</div>
        <div class="item">Another item 3</div>
        ...
    </div>
```

Comment: This is perfectly straightforward and easy to understand. I would totally mark this as a accepted answer if there wouldn't be shorter one and without the for loop, so anyways thank you very much! It's perfectly functional and especially easy to customize solution.

Comment: I like @adeneo 's solution too, it's quite elaborate. Thank you for letting me know my answer was helpful. This is what SO is about, IMHO. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

> As I doubt that there will be pure CSS solution

For a pure `css` solution you can utilize [`General siblings combinator`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) selector `~`.

> The elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in
>   the document tree and the element represented by the first sequence
>   precedes (not necessarily immediately) the element represented by the
>   second one.

Use two selectors. At first selector, match required element. At second selector match elements following first selector, set default value for properties set at first matched element or use `unset`.

```css
/* match third `div.item` */
.parent div.item ~ div.item ~ div.item {
  color: sienna;
  font-size: 2em;
}
/* match fourth through last `div.item` */
.parent div.item ~ div.item ~ div.item ~ div.item {
  color: unset;
  font-size: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="randomclass">...</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="randomclassdifferentname">...</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7</div>
  ...
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="anotherclass">...</div>
  <div class="item">Another item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Another item 2</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div class="item">Another item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Another item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Another item 5</div>
  ...
</div>
```

---

> I need to select only nth .item div class child of a .parent div
>   (counter resets for every parent node).
>
> For example I want to select every **third "div.item"** element so I'm
>   expecting to affect elements with content **"Item 3", "Item 6",
>   "Another item 3"**.

Did not initially notice that requirement was to select every third element.

You can still utilize `css` `General sibling combinator` selector with `.querySelector()`, which returns a single element, within a `javascript` function to return expected result.

The function currently accepts a parent element as selector string or `DOM` element, descendant element selector, number referencing the distance between selections of descendant selector, a callback to call for each matched element, returns matched elements within an array.

`for` loop within `for..of` loop iterates a maximum of `childSelector.length / nth` times. A selector string is constructed using the `nth` number parameter within the `for` loop; `.querySelector()` returns the single element, then increments the `nth` parameter which creates selector matching `nth` element from previous matched element for next iteration; eliminating the necessity for `for` loop to iterate all `childSelector.length` elements of `parentSelector` to match the required selectors.

```js
const gen = function* (arg) {
    yield* arg[Symbol.iterator] ? arg : [arg] 
};
window.onload = function() {
  // `parentSelector`: `".parent"`, `document.querySelector(".parent")`,
  // `document.querySelectorAll(".parent"),
  // `document.getElementsByClassName(".parent")`
  // `childSelector`: `".item"`; `nth`: `3`; `callback`: function
  function nthElement(parentSelector, childSelector, nth, callback) {
    let [nthparents, selector, n, items] = [
          typeof parentSelector === "string"
            ? document.querySelectorAll(parentSelector)
            : [...gen(parentSelector)]
          , childSelector
          , nth
          , []
        ];
    for (let nthp of nthparents) {
      for (let i = n; i <= nthp.querySelectorAll(selector).length; i += n) {
        let item = nthp.querySelector(Array(i).fill(selector).join("~"));
        items.push(item);
        callback.call(item, i, item, nthp)
      }
    };
    return items
  }
  // select every `nth` third `.item` element  
  // that is a child of `.parent` element
  let items = nthElement(document.querySelectorAll(".parent"), ".item", 3
              , function (i, nth, nthParent) {
                  console.log(i, nth, nthParent);
                  this.style.color = "sienna";
                  this.style.fontSize = "2em";
              });
  console.log(items);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="randomclass">...</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="randomclassdifferentname">...</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7</div>
  ...
  <div class="randomclass">...</div>
  <div class="randomclass">...</div>
  <div class="randomclass">...</div>
  <div class="item">Item 8</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="anotherclass">...</div>
  <div class="item">Another item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Another item 2</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div class="item">Another item 3</div>
  <div class="anotherclass">...</div>
  <div class="item">Another item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Another item 5</div>
  ...
  <div class="anotherclass">...</div>
  <div class="anotherclass">...</div>
  <div class="anotherclass">...</div>
  <div class="item">Another item 6</div>
</div>
```

Using jQuery

```js
$(function() {
  function nthElement(childSelector, nth, callback) {
    let [nthparents, selector, n, items] = [
        Array.from(this)
        , childSelector
        , nth
        , []
        ];
    for (let nthp of nthparents) {
      for (let i = n; i <= nthp.querySelectorAll(selector).length; i += n) {
        let item = nthp.querySelector(Array(i).fill(selector).join("~"));
        items.push(item);
        callback.call(item, i, item, nthp)
      }
    };
    return jQuery(items)
  }
  // set `nthElement` as a jQuery method
  $.fn.extend({nthElement: nthElement});

  // select every third `.item` element  that is a child of `.parent` element
  var items = $(".parent").nthElement(".item", 3, function(i, nth, nthParent) {
    console.log(i, nth, nthParent);
    $(this).css({color: "sienna",fontSize: "2em"});   
  });      
  console.log(items);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="randomclass">...</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="randomclassdifferentname">...</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7</div>
  ...
  <div class="randomclass">...</div>
  <div class="randomclass">...</div>
  <div class="randomclass">...</div>
  <div class="item">Item 8</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="anotherclass">...</div>
  <div class="item">Another item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Another item 2</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div class="item">Another item 3</div>
  <div class="anotherclass">...</div>
  <div class="item">Another item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Another item 5</div>
  ...
  <div class="anotherclass">...</div>
  <div class="anotherclass">...</div>
  <div class="anotherclass">...</div>
  <div class="item">Another item 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't selected *Item 6*

Comment: @Mohammad Ah, missed that OP is trying to select every third element

Comment: Thank you very much for such a long explainable post. It hurts me to not mark this as the answer especially when you put this much of effort into it. But it's just too complex and complicated. In my original post I was asking for a simple jQuery solution because otherwise I would think up the longer one myself. But anyway thank you thousand times! :)

Comment: `yield* Array.from([arg])`? That's just `yield arg`.

Comment: @Ryan Found it "The yield keyword actually returns an IteratorResult" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield

Comment: @Ryan This is the briefest have been able to compose so far `yield* arg[Symbol.iterator] ? arg : [arg]`

Answer (score -1):

nth-child selector is not class sensitive. It selects element by name not by class. See [jquery nth-child](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

> The :nth-child(n) pseudo-class is easily confused with :eq(n), even though the two can result in dramatically different matched elements. With :nth-child(n), all children are counted, regardless of what they are, and the specified element is selected only if it matches the selector attached to the pseudo-class. With :eq(n) only the selector attached to the pseudo-class is counted, not limited to children of any other element, and the (n+1)th one (n is 0-based) is selected.

Though eq(n) is class sensitive but it not supports equation as parameter.

So I think there's no direct way to use css only to implement it.

Try it also with some js codes.

Comment: Well I explained why the `nth-child` selector is not working in this case in my original post. And you are not right that it selects elements by name, no, it selects just child nodes, it doesn't care about any names at all. `nth-of-type` selects elements by the name. But anyway thanks :)

Comment: You misundersood it. nth-child selects child nodes by child name not by class. So div.item:nth-child(3n) select child divs(name) not by class(item).

Comment: Incorrect or you may just don't understand. I never said this. You said _select_ but that is in case of `nth-child` too general term. In short, `nth-child` does two things: 1) it counts child elements and while counting it doesn't care about NAMEs, it just counts NODEs. Again: While counting, it does not take in account their names/types/etc what so ever. 2) Once the counting is done, it applies the effect only on nodes identified by the preceding selector (class/type/etc). See the documentation if you still don't understand.

Comment: U are right. I didnt recognize that nth-child only applies to child(node) no matter what the child is. LOL.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't possible with pure CSS selectors. However, this is something achievable if you have the flexibility to use a unique tag name instead of div.item. Here is something you could do, if you could change the div.item elements to a p tag.

```css
.parent p:nth-of-type(3n) {
  color: red;
}
.parent {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.item {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="randomclass">Random</div>
  <p class="item">Item 1</p>
  <p class="item">Item 2</p>
  <p class="item">Item 3</p>
  <div class="randomclassdifferentname">Random different Name</div>
  <p class="item">Item 4</p>
  <p class="item">Item 5</p>
  <p class="item">Item 6</p>
  <p class="item">Item 7</p>

</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="anotherclass">Another Random</div>
  <p class="item">Another item 1</p>
  <p class="item">Another item 2</p>
  <div>Random Text</div>
  <p class="item">Another item 3</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But unfortunately I would like it to be div element. Otherwise I would also use the `nth-of-type` :) or just simple css selector. But anyway thanks for the try!