# Expand an iterable element or non-iterable element into an array without checking element .length

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, iterable

Given `html`

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

calling `document.querySelector("div")` returns the first `div` element, where `.length` is not a property of the return value.

Calling `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList` having a `.length` property.

The difference between the two return values of `.querySelector()` and `.querySelectorAll()` is that the former is not an iterable; and error will be thrown when attempting to use the `spread element` to expand the element into an array.

In the following examples consider that either `div` or `divs` is a parameter received within the body of a functions call. Thus, as far as can gather, it is not possible to determine if the variable was defined as a result of `Element.querySelector()`, `Element.querySelectorAll()`, `document.querySelector()` or `document.querySelectorAll()`; further the difference between `.querySelector()` and `.querySelectorAll()` can only be checked using `.length`.

```js
var div = document.querySelector("div");
for (let el of div) {
  console.log(".querySelector():", el)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

logs

```
Uncaught TypeError: div[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
```

while

```js
var div = document.querySelectorAll("div");
for (let el of div) {
  console.log(".querySelectorAll():", el)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

returns expected result; that is, `document.querySelectorAll("div")` is expanded to fill the iterable array.

We can get the expected result at `.querySelector()` by setting `div` as an element of an `Array`

```
[div]
```

at `for..of` `iterable` parameter.

The closest have come to using same pattern for both or either `.querySelector()` or `.querySelectorAll()` is using `callback` of `Array.from()` and the `.tagName` of the variable, and `spread element`.
Though this omits additional selectors that may have been called with `.querySelector()`, for example `.querySelector("div.abc")`.

```js
var div = document.querySelector("div");
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
var elems = Array.from({length:div.length || 1}, function(_, i) {
  return [...div.parentElement.querySelectorAll(
    (div.tagName || div[0].tagName))
         ][i]
});

for (let el of elems) {
  console.log(".querySelector():", el)
}

elems = Array.from({length:divs.length || 1}, function(_, i) {
  return [...divs[0].parentElement.querySelectorAll(
    (divs.tagName || divs[0].tagName))
         ][i]
});

for (let el of elems) {
  console.log("querySelectorAll:", el)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

This does not provide adequate accuracy for additional reasons;  `Element.querySelector()` could have been originally passed to function, instead of `document.querySelector()`, similarly for `.querySelectorAll().
Not sure if it is possible to retrieve the exact selector passed to`.querySelector, All` without modifying the native function?

The desired pattern would accept the variable, and expand the contents of the iterable into an array if an `.querySelectorAll()` was used; which would treat `.getElementsByTagName()`, `.getElementsByClassName()`, `.getElementsByTagName()`, `.getElementsByName()` the same; or set the single value returned by `.querySelector()` as element of the array.

Note, the current working solution is

```
div.length ? div : [div]
```

which iterates `div` if `div` has a `.length` property, possibly an iterable, though simply have a `.length` property and not be an `iterable`; else set `div` as single element of an array, an iterable.

```js
var div = document.querySelector("div");
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
var elems = div.length ? div : [div];

for (let el of elems) {
  console.log(".querySelector():", el)
}

var elems = divs.length ? divs : [divs];

for (let el of elems) {
  console.log("querySelectorAll:", el)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Can this be achieved

- without checking the `.length` of the variable?
- without referencing the element three times on same line?

Can the approach of the working solution

- be improved; that is should `[Symbol.iterator]` of `div` be checked instead of `.length`?
- is there magic using `.spread element` or `rest element` which could allow omission of checking `.length` of object?
- would using a `Generator`, `Array.prototype.reduce()` or other approach change the need to check the `.length` or `[Symbol.iterator]` property of a variable before expanding the element into an array?

Or, is the above the approach the briefest possible given the difference between objects which are `iterable` or not `iterable`?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Use the same pattern to expand a parameter passed to a function within the body of the function into an array; whether the variable is an iterable or is not an iterable. Determine if `div.length ? div : [div]` is the briefest possible pattern to use to check if parameter possibly has an iterable property. And if checking `div.length` is adequate way to check if an object is an `iterable`? Given parameter is one of, for example `.querySelector()` : not an iterable, `.querySelectorAll()` : an iterable.

Comment: Is this a long way of saying you want a function that turns an object into a one-element list if it’s not already iterable?

Comment: @Ryan Yes. `div.length ? div : [div]` is relatively brief, and achieves this. Though is that correct approach? That is `{abc:123, length:3}` has a `.length` property, though is not necessarily an `iterable`, and not an array.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18884249/5647260) help? `isIterable(divs) ? divs : [divs]`

Comment: It is not sufficient for every iterable, no. I’d do this: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.from but create a single-element array instead of one with no elements if length isn’t an integer after step 11.

Comment: @AndrewLi Yes, that helps. Checking `.length` is not adequate.

Comment: @Ryan Tried using `Array.from()` , `Array.of()`, `Array.fill()` to create an array before, then fill with either element that does not have `.length` property or element that does have `.length` property, though they return different results when `spread element` `...` is used to expand the array; `array[0]` if set with both iterable and non-iterable as a single element; `.querySelector()` the single element, `.querySelectorAll()` a `NodeList`. Where `for..of` is expecting an array of elements, not a `NodeList`. Can you post an Answer illustrating the approach you are describing?

Comment: Note, the Answers at linked Question each return a `Boolean`. They do not provide a solution for converting non-iterable to an iterable or array and returning the iterable or array. OP of linked Question did not ask how to convert a non-iterable to an iterable or array, and return the converted value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d do more or less [what `Array.from` does](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.from), but check the type of `length` instead of always converting it:

```
const itemsOrSingle = items => {
    const iteratorFn = items[Symbol.iterator]

    if (iteratorFn) {
        return Array.from(iteratorFn.call(items))
    }

    const length = items.length

    if (typeof length !== 'number') {
        return [items]
    }

    const result = []

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result.push(items[i])
    }

    return result
}
```

Comment: What is purpose of `if (typeof length !== 'number') {
        return [items]
    }`?

Comment: @guest271314: If it's not a number, it doesn't make a lot of sense to loop from 0 to it. You could change that check to `length === undefined`, though. There's really no right way to do duck typing here.

Comment: If `items` is iterable, could `items` be returned without call to `Array.from()`? What is purpose of using `Array.from()` in that particular `if` statement  block?

Comment: @guest271314: Sure, you can do that if you want an iterable instead of an array.

Comment: fwiw cobbled together an approach which utilizes `generator function`, `yield*` expression, `try..catch` to review caught error if parameter passed to generator function is not an iterable object, `Array.from()` to yield an iterable or array from passed parameter  http://stackoverflow.com/a/40199709/

Comment: Implemented at [jQuery alternative to nth-child selector that supports classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40187310/jquery-alternative-to-nth-child-selector-that-supports-classes)